# Mapping Keys from an Array to an extJS Grid

Tags: php, arrays, extjs

I have a PHP script which responds with an array in the form of:

```
[0] => dataOne
[1] => dataTwo
[2] => dataThree
[3] => dataFour
```

I would like to map these to a grid in my view but am having a bit of trouble doing it.

Here are the pieces that I have created so far:

```
Ext.define('OptionalCookbook', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    {name: 'cookbook'}
  ]
});

var optionalCookbooksStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  autoLoad: true,
  autoSync: true,
  model: 'OptionalCookbook',
  proxy: {
  type: 'ajax',
  url: 'data.php',
  reader: {
    type: 'array'
  },
  writer: {
    type: 'json'
}
}
});

var optionalCookbooksGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  store: optionalCookbooksStore,
  width: '100%',
  height: 200,
  title: 'Optional Cookbooks',
  columns: [
{
  text: 'Role',
  width: 100,
  sortable: false,
  hideable: false,
  dataIndex: 'cookbook'
}
]
});
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Please make a fiddle. I fear that your output format is neither valid json nor valid XML, and cannot be parsed by available ExtJS readers. Write your own reader.

Comment: I'll create a fiddle in a moment. I'm currently trying to pre-process the JSON I receive from the API and adding my own roots in order to be able to display it nicely in the Grid component using the dataIndex property.